# What type of sorting algorithm resembles the most to this code? (if any).

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am learning programming (with Javascript) and as a test I decided to find a way to wrote an algorithm to sort and array of strings, this is what I came up with.

```
// test of a sorting algorithm 
var steps = 0;
var steps2 = 0;
var array  = ['assa', 'erer', 'qwqw', 'ggdffdghdg', 'sdsdethhhghg', 'aaaaaa', 'gthfyjfdsfdf', 'qwqwwere', 'jygyghhf', '1', '0', '345', 'sfsdsddsfsf', 'eee3ew33', '1dwd', 'ddd2'];


var array2  = ['erer', 'jygyghhf', '1', '0', '345', 'sfsdsddsfsf', 'eee3ew33', '1dwd', 'ddd2'];
console.log('array before sort');
console.log(array);
function simpleSort(array) {
    let length = array.length;
    let currentPos = 1;
    while (currentPos < length) {
        let pivot = 0;
        do {
            let currentValue = array[currentPos];
            if (currentValue > array[pivot]) {

                array.splice(currentPos, 1);
                array.splice(pivot, 0, currentValue);
                steps++;
            }
            steps2++;   
            pivot++;

        }
        while (currentPos > pivot);
        currentPos++;
    }
    console.log(array);
    console.log('steps = ' + steps);
    console.log('steps2 = ' + steps2);
}
console.log('********************');
console.log('array after sort');
simpleSort(array);

console.log('********************');
console.log('array after sort with array.sort() and array.reverse() buit in functions');
array.sort();
console.log(array.reverse());
```

What type of sorting algorithm would resemble most to this code and what would be the big O of this

Comment: It's like a Quick Sort, except not so quick :) The problem is with those calls to `.splice()`, which introduces a lot of unnecessary overhead. A real Quick Sort does the partitioning more efficiently and ends up O(*n log n*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is the same as the following, so it has a similar structure to the `O(n^2)` sort algorithms.

```
function simpleSort(array) {
    for (var currentPos = 1; currentPos < array.length; currentPos++) {
        for (var pivot = 0; pivot < currentPos; pivot++) {
            let currentValue = array[currentPos];
            if (currentValue > array[pivot]) {
                array.splice(currentPos, 1);
                array.splice(pivot, 0, currentValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With an input of `[6, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 3]`, after each iteration you have:

```
6   3 5 4 1 8 6 3
6 3   5 4 1 8 6 3
6 5 3   4 1 8 6 3
6 5 4 3   1 8 6 3
6 5 4 3 1   8 6 3
8 6 5 4 3 1   6 3
8 6 6 5 4 3 1   3
8 6 6 5 4 3 3 1
```

This shows that the left side is sorted at each step, and increases in size by one each iteration. This is the same as [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

The `if` condition can only be true once for each iteration because after the splice, `currentValue` will become equal to the smallest value in the left array and compared to larger values each time. So it has `O(n^2)` time complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the matrix really helped me in visualizing what the code is doing. A follow up question, is there any difference in steps between your code and mine? or is just a difference in aesthetic? (yours is a lot more clearer than mine)

Comment: @FidelVe I changed the grouping of the variables because it can make the structure clearer but all the actual operations should be the same.